# Large scale iOS Branding

Tags: ios, branding

My work over the last few years has involved making re-brandable iOS and Android apps for a large number of customers who each specify their own names and logos for their apps.

Doing this sustainably for iOS has been an interesting challenge.

My previous workplace had an interesting flow that involved taking the compiled ipa file and unzipping it and inserting the new assets (app info plists, icons etc) they wanted via an automated build process involving many custom scripts. This was discussed by the dev team at a WWDC dev lab where it was begrudgingly accepted as an "ok" method for the hundreds of apps that this needed to be done for.

At my current workplace we make use of NUI (https://github.com/tombenner/nui) to also add customised themes per customer, right now we have a separate target made in XCode for each customer with their own image assets and extracted config files for settings customisation etc.

An alternative way used in the legacy version of the app was to swap in asset files before invoking XCodebuild via a script that cycled through folders representing each client and contained their unique profiles and settings.

Right now as it stands, multiple targets is ok for the 50 or so customers we have but won't quite cut it for the 400 or so we expect as product uptake increases.. we're already facing issues with merging and having new classes not getting "ticked" for targets as the code base grows.

I was wondering if anyone has tried other approaches to branding besides the ones I mentioned?